# Binance API - Get current position and current position cost

Tags: python, binance

I am trying to fetch data on my current open position on SPOT binance market.

I am trying to get my open position on binance SPOT market, but can't seem to find in the docs what function should I use.
I am using ccxt to fetch data in combination with the Binance API.

The only code I was able to run so far is this:

```py
binance = ccxt.binance({ 'enableRateLimit': True,
                            'apiKey': config.API_KEY,
                            'secret': config.API_SECRET})

bin_bal = binance.fetch_balance()
```

But fetch balance does not return position cost (how much it costed on average to enter a position), it only shows the current balance of each coin.